# Rearranging infinite sums in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following seems like a natural higher-dimensional generalization of the one-dimensional result on rearrranging absolutely convergent infinite series.

> Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and suppose we're given a map $f:\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{C}$. Suppose further that we're given bijections $\sigma:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^k$, $\pi:\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}^k$. Then $$\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i_{2}=1}^{\infty} \cdots \sum_{i_{k}=1}^{\infty} f(i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_k)=\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i_{2}=1}^{\infty} \cdots \sum_{i_{k}=1}^{\infty} f(\pi(i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_k))= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(\sigma(i))$$
> provided at least one of the three sums converges absolutely.

This seems like the sort of thing that one would find in an analysis textbook, but I have not been able to find a proof. Rudin only proves the case where $k=2$ and $\sigma(x,y)=(y,x)$.

> Does anyone know a reference for the above theorem? Or if the theorem is straightforward enough that you think you can write up the proof, please feel free to do that (although my hunch is that it could be messy).

I find that this also sometimes has concrete applications, and isn't just a mere "curiosity". For instance, oftentimes we need to work with a power series of the form $\sum_{i} \sum_{j} c_{ij}x^{a_{ij}}$ where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{N}$. The "canonical" form of  writing the series ought to be $$\sum_{k} \left(\sum_{(i,j) \ \text{such that} \ a_{ij} = k} c_{ij}\right)x^k$$

but we require a certain formal justification to write it as such.

Comment: this can be seen as a consequence of Tonelli's theorem. For a more elementary approach take a look to the book *Analysis I* of Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher (but as Im reading this is same result than in Rudin's book for $k=2$). If you knows the case for $k=2$ try to use induction to generalize it.